# How does MySQL rotate binary log files when number extension reaches its maximum?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, binlog, mysqlbinlog

Assume the bin-log file format is: `something-bin-log.000122`. With each file has a maximum of 1GB size before rotating, and with cap on the number of old binary log files - say 14 days.

What will be the next file when the current one is `something-bin-log.999999` and it is about to get rotated?

Will the next binary log file be `something-bin-log.000001`? If so, how to prevent this from happening and use a bigger numeric extension instead?

Comment: That _should_ take a long time.  Are you somehow racing to the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error is generated when the numbers run out:

[source code reference](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/binlog.cc#L3454)

Comment: To add more info, MySQL will not stop on 999,999 as it's merely a formatting thing. The limit for the numeric extension is actually 0x7FFFFFFF or  2147483647.

Sources:
http://adamcscott.blogspot.com/2014/06/mysql-55-maximum-sequence-in-binary-logs.html
https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/binlog.cc#L3471